# How Do I Prove that $\mathbb{E}^d\nrightarrow (l_4)_3$?

Tags: convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

**Question**

Prove that for all $d\geq 1, \mathbb{E}^d\nrightarrow (l_4)_3$.

That is, we need to prove that there is no way to colour the points in $\mathbb{E}^d$ with 3 colours such that there will always exist 4 collinear points, evenly spaced 1 unit apart, that are all the same colour.

**Note:** Here, $\mathbb{E}^d$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$ with Euclidean norm-2, $l_k$ is a configuration of $k$ points in a line, separated by unit distances, and r is the number of colours. So, $(l_k)_r$ would mean colouring $\mathbb{E}^d$ using $r$ number of colours to get monochromatic $k$-points.

**Note:**
We may consider $c(v)=\lfloor 2\lVert v \rVert^2\rfloor mod 3$ (I used $c(v)=\lfloor \lVert v \rVert^2\rfloor mod 4$ for $\mathbb{E}^d\nrightarrow (l_3)_4$, and the solution worked out well). Here, $c$ is the colouring function, $v$ is vertex (or points).

**Attempt**
We use prove by contradiction. Suppose:

$c(x-u)=c(x)=c(x+u)=c(x+2u)=r$, where $r\in \{0,1,2\}$.

Then, we have the following equations:

$2\lVert x-u \rVert^2 = 3a+r+\alpha$

$2\lVert x \rVert^2 = 3b+r+\beta$

$2\lVert x+u \rVert^2 = 3c+r+\gamma$

$2\lVert x+2u \rVert^2 = 3a+r+\theta$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\theta \in [0,1)$.

Expanding the norms and simplifying the resulting equations by taking one equation form another, we have:

$4=3(a-b-c+d)+\alpha -\beta -\gamma +\theta$.

Although this looks like a contradiction since $-2<\alpha -\beta -\gamma +\theta<2$. However, since we are dealing with $mod 3$ here, I am thinking of re-writing this equation as:

$1=3(a-b-c+d-1)+\alpha -\beta -\gamma +\theta$.

The problem is, this is not a contradiction anymore. I am not sure if there is something I am mixing up here. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is overflowing with undefined terms. How is anyone supposed to be able to understand it, let alone answer it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have edited the question by defining the terms. I hope it will be readable now.

Comment: OK. I don't understand "there is no way to do X so that Y will always happen." I could understand "there is no way to do X so that Y will happen" (but I don't think that's what you want). I could understand "there is a way to do X so that Y will not happen".

Comment: @GerryMyerson That is, we will not achieve monochromatic 4-points if we use 3 colours.

Comment: @GerryMyerson By assuming we will have monochromatic points, I expanded the vector norm and managed to get the equation $4=3(a-b-c+d)+\alpha-\beta-\gamma+\theta$, which should lead to a contradiction, where \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \theta \in [0,1). So, we should get a contradiction. My knowledge of modular arithmetic is a bit rusty. I don’t know if I should do something about the 4 by **splitting** it into 3 and 1.

Comment: If we color the origin purple, and color some other point aquamarine, and color all the rest of the points burnt sienna, then there certainly will be four collinear points, evenly spaced one unit apart, that are all the same color. So there *is* a way to color etc., etc. You must mean something different to what you have written.

Comment: What's the point of putting a bounty on a question that doesn't make any sense? Also, the new edit introduces a bounty of undefined terms: $u,a,b,c$. Well, $c$ is defined as the coloring function, but then it is used again to mean something entirely different, in the formula for $2\|x+u\|^2$. Sloppy, sloppy, sloppy.

Comment: There **is** a way to colour the points in $\mathbb{E}^d$ with 3 colours such that there exist $4$ collinear points, evenly spaced $1$ unit apart, that are all the same colour.

Comment: @Alex, I gave such a way, two comments up from yours.